# Find total flux of F across S

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-fields

Let $S$ be the surface defined by $z = e^{1-x^2-y^2}$, $z\geq 1$, oriented by the upward normal, and let $\mathbf{F}(x,y,z) = (x,y,2-2z)$. Find the total flux of $\mathbf{F}$ across $S$.

So I  find the boundary of the surface which is a closed circle C, and use stokes theorem to switch from a surface integral to a different kind of integral. But I don't know what to do next. Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax and see [MathJax tutorial](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers. Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: To find the flux through $S$, you need to use the divergence theorem, rather than Stokes' theorem. The statement is 
$\text{Flux through $S$} := \oint_\Sigma \mathbf{F}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}}\,dS \overset{\text{div. thrm.}}{=}\iint_{\operatorname{int}\Sigma}\operatorname{div}\mathbf{F}\,dV.$

Comment: thank you so much. I finally got it.